# method setLatestEventInfo(myService, String, String, PendingIntent) is undefined for the type Notification

Tags: android, eclipse

This code use to work ...

```
public void displayNotification(String msg) { 
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.aow, msg, System.currentTimeMillis());
    // The PendingIntent will launch activity if the user selects this
    // notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this,
                    com.redcricket.whale_ship_essex_banner.whale_ship_essex_bannerActivity.class),
            0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
            com.redcricket.whale_ship_essex_banner.whale_ship_essex_bannerActivity.track_titles[ currentTrack ], contentIntent);

    manager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

... but now I get these error messages:

```
The constructor Notification(int, CharSequence, long) is deprecated
The method setLatestEventInfo(whale_ship_essex_bannerService, String, String, PendingIntent) is undefined for the type Notification
```

Can someone please tell what I need to change or to some documentation about how to rewrite this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [NotificationBuilder](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) instead of constructor.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentTitle("Some title")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builder.setLargeIcon(bm);
Notification notification = builder.build();
```

Comment: When I put that code into my code I get this error:`NotificationCompat cannot be resolved to a type`.

Comment: Add support v4 dependency to your gradle file: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'

Comment: Sorry for being so dense and thank you for your help.  But how do I add support v4 dependency to my gradle file?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? If you do, find a file called build.gradle (there are several, but you need this one, which placed in app directory), and put line "compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'" to "dependencies" unit

Comment: Nope. I can't.  I am in a limbo because I use APK Expansion Files and AdMob.  So I use eclipse like Google documentation says to.  If you have the magic command line way of doing this I'd sure appreciate it.  I can build my app that do not have AdMob ads via `ant` on centos7.

Comment: In this case use this instruction to add support library to your project http://www.badeaufsicht.org/how-to-use-the-android-support-package-with-eclipse-ide/

Comment: Thanks Denis.  I had to up my minSdkVersion from 8 to 11 in my AndroidManifest.xml file like so: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />`